# Does apple provide any media transport controls to use in my app

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I am writing an app that plays a soundtrack. I am using `AVAudioPlayer`, I implemented a playlist and all the logic to handle it as well as transport controls (Play, stop, rewind, forward, and cue). Now I am proceeding to connect the interface which I could create myself, but I want to know if cocoa touch has one I can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transport controls are called [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html) and you can implement them like so:

```
// Init
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

// TODO: handle errors
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
[commandCenter.playCommand addTargetWithHandler:^(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
    [weakSelf.player play];
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

[commandCenter.pauseCommand addTargetWithHandler:^(MPRemoteCommandEvent *event) {
    [weakSelf.player pause];
    return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatusSuccess;
}];

NSString *url = @"file url here";

// TODO: handle errors
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] error:nil];
[self.player play];
```

This will give you controls on the lock screen and on the "swipe up" screen. You can add more functions (like, seek, etc) and also metadata via [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7-SW1).

Comment: Thanks that is working already, my question is related to user interface inside the app, is there UI control in the likes of MPVolumeView that includes play, stop, ff, rw?

Comment: Ah, in that case you could switch to AVPlayer + AVPlayerViewController.